# How to align bootstrap 4 tooltips to the top-left of the elements?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

In my bootstrap v4.6.x, I am using tooltip's. By default the tooltip is aligned to the center of the element. Due to the design requirements, I wanted to have the tooltip aligned to the top-left of the element as below:
[image]

I have tried below CSS and did not worked:

```
.tooltip-inner {
    text-align: left!important;
}
```

**Update 1**
JSfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/kingBethal/x0c2sm5u/5/)

Comment: These are the options you have for bs4 tooltips: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/tooltips/#options Since bs4 uses popper for tooltips these should also work: https://popper.js.org

Comment: Tried `data-placements`, including `auto`. They all align the tooltip to the center of the element, I wanted it to align to the top-left of the element.

Comment: Then we need more information on how to reproduce your problem. Create a fiddle here so we can see your problem.

Comment: Here is the JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kingBethal/x0c2sm5u/5/

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to access popper within this bundled bootstrap JS ... With plain bs tooltips the placement you want is not possible. I [suggest to use tippy.js](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/) as an additional library for tooltips. scroll down a bit to see all placement options available. (They also use popper.js in the background, just a better implementation than bootstrap's one)

Comment: I have used un-bundled bootstarp JS files. Any possibilities to achieve this without adding another library? https://jsfiddle.net/kingBethal/x0c2sm5u/8/

Comment: Now you can use `Popper.createPopper` like shown in the [tutorial of popper.js. ](https://popper.js.org/docs/v2/tutorial/)